# How to get a list of all the functions that are invoked/called in a cpp file?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

I understand that we can use gcc's '`-ffunction-sections`' compiler option along with '`--gc-sections`' linker option to identify unused functions in the source.

But, is there a way to list out all the functions that are being invoked in a cpp file?

Comment: You can't know which extern functions are invoked without whole-program analysis, and even then you may get false positives for functions that may be accessed with `dlsym` at runtime.  The usual suspects for C++ introspection hackery come into play - clang can output XML dumps, gccxml does similar for older GCC versions (not sure if it's maintained), there are some commercial tools.  Requests for lists/recommendations for such tools is actually off-topic on S.O..

Comment: Hi Toni, Thanks a lot for making the concepts clear. Let me better describe the problem, "We are generating one map file with unused functions list for every module in our Software package. But we are also interested in knowing about all the functions (even if they are extern) that are being invoked or called from each Modules in our Software package." So was wondering , if we can log that info using gcc.

Comment: the only thing that comes to mind and is vaguely potentially useful that I haven't already mentioned is gcov, which might let you find out which of your functions are being invoked, though it might slow down execution.

Comment: Using GCC, have you looked at the map output it can generate?  You don't specify when you need to know this, but if you can compile the code and then inspect the map file that GCC produces, I believe you can get a list of every function that is called (and probably some other stuff too).